Button That Makes a Variable Change Between Two Values Over a Specified Time Duration
The code below produces a button that toggles the right cell bracket margin of the current notebook between 0 and 150.
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
  CellBracketOptions -> {"Margins" -> Dynamic@{0, w}}];

indent = False;
Button["Run", 
 If[indent,
  {w = 150; indent = False;},
  {w = 0; indent = True;}]]

Now, instead of the margin toggling between 0 and 150, I'd like the margin to change from 0 to 150 (and vica versa) over a specified time interval (say 2 seconds). In other words... I'm trying to animate the change in the margin so that it happens continuously over 2 seconds on each button press.
Edit 1:  I decided to try using Animator[].  I'm pretty close.  It works for changing the margin from 0 to 150 on first click, but still need it to change from 150 back to 0 on second click.
DynamicModule[{},
 w = 0;
 SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
  CellBracketOptions -> {"Margins" -> Dynamic@{0, w}}];
 
 Animator[Dynamic[w], {0, 150, 1},
  AppearanceElements -> "PlayPauseButton",
  AnimationDirection -> Forward,
  AnimationRate -> 75,
  AnimationRepetitions -> 1,
  AnimationRunning -> False]]

Here is a video of it in action.


AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward ?

@Domen.  Great idea.. but can't figure out to stop it half way.

Does it fit your needs?
DynamicModule[{w = 0, running = False, direction = Forward},
 Button[
  Row[{
    Animator[
     Dynamic[w,
      { Automatic, 
        (CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], {CellBracketOptions, "Margins"}] = {0, #}) & }
      ], 
     {0, 150, 1}, 
     AppearanceElements -> "None",
     AnimationDirection -> Dynamic@direction,
     AnimationRate -> 75,
     AnimationRepetitions -> 1,
     AnimationRunning -> Dynamic@running],
    Dynamic@w
    }],
  direction = If[w == 0, Forward, Backward];
  running = True,
  Enabled -> Dynamic[! running]
  ]
 ]


Something like this?
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
  CellBracketOptions -> {"Margins" -> Dynamic[{0, Clock[150, 2]}]}
]

Obviously this can be extended to use control variables etc. inside the Dynamic.
You can also do:
w := Clock[150, 2];
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
  CellBracketOptions -> {"Margins" -> Dynamic[{0, w}]}
]

You can then turn the animation off by setting w = 0.
